# Show and hide MBprogressHUD multiply times in a swift function

Tags: swift, mbprogresshud

a function is doing multiply things in blocks. I want to hide hud when a task is done and shows the hud for the next task. but it shows the hud at first and hides it in the end. whats the problem?
This is my code:

```
@IBAction func syncBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: view, animated: true)
        loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.indeterminate
        loadingNotification.label.text = "Syncing with server..."
        myAPI.SendInspectResultGetMaterials { (materials, result) in
            if result {
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
                loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.indeterminate
                loadingNotification.label.text = "Generating Database..."

                self.GenerationTheDatabase(materials: materials!, Completion: { result in

                        self.myAPI.GetSetVals { (setvals) in
                            _ = RealmService.shared.deleteAllFromObject(RealmSetVals())
                            for item in setvals.value {
                                let newSetVal = RealmSetVals(Id: item.id, ReasonType: item.type, Name: item.name)
                                _ = RealmService.shared.create(newSetVal)
                            }
                            self.myAPI.GetUserInfo(Completion: { (userInfo) in


                                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                                let aDipach = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
                                aDipach.async {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "Synced Successfully")
                                    }
                                }
                            })

                        }

                })
            }
            else{
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                let aDipach = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
                aDipach.async {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Error while syncing")
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

I know for using hud I have to use blocks in code and I did it but it doesn't work till the end

Comment: Why don't you just change the text instead of showing it and hiding it again?

Comment: It' wont change the text till the end @Sulthan

Comment: I think you need you show and hide it in every start of the function, depending when it finishes and when it starts. Or maybe I'm not understanding the real problem